# Interpolate/Resize 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 3D array holding voxels from a mri dataset. The model could be stretched along one or more directions. E.g. the voxel size (x,y,z) could be 0.5x0.5x2 mm. Now I want to resample the 3D array into an array holding 1,1,1 mm voxels. For this I need to make the x/y dimensions smaller and the z dimension bigger and interpolate the voxel values. 
My question is: Is there a simple function in numpy or scipy for doing such a resampling of a simple 3d array?

Loading model from *.nii file:

```
img = nib.load(sFileName)
array = np.array(img.dataobj).astype("uint8") # 3d array with e.g. 0.5,0.5,2 mm
# TODO resample
```

Comment: `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator` probably works for your case.

Comment: I will try it out.

Comment: "clinched"? What does that mean?

Comment: With PyTorch you can easily use the Upsample from torch.nn to Upscale images of 1,2, and 3 dimensions with various methods including trilinear interpolation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### ndimage.zoom

This is probably the best approach, the [zoom method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) is designed for precisely this kind of task.

```
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
new_array = zoom(array, (0.5, 0.5, 2))
```

changes the size in each dimension by the specified factor. If the original shape of array was, say, `(40, 50, 60)`, the new one will be `(20, 25, 120)`.

#### signal.resample_poly

SciPy has a [large set of methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) for signal processing. Most relevant here are [decimate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html#scipy.signal.decimate) and [resample_poly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample_poly.html#scipy.signal.resample_poly). I use the latter below

```
from scipy.signal import resample_poly
factors = [(1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
for k in range(3):
    array = resample_poly(array, factors[k][0], factors[k][1], axis=k)
```

The factors (which must be integers) are of up- and down-sampling. That is:

- (1, 2) means size divided by 2
- (2, 1) means size multiplied by 2
- (2, 3) would mean up by 2 then down by 3, so the size is multiplied by 2/3

Possible downside: the process happens independently in each dimension, so the spatial structure may not be taken into account as well as by ndimage methods.

#### RegularGridInterpolator

This is more hands-on, but also more laborious and without the benefit of filtering: straightforward downsampling. We have to make a grid for the interpolator, using original step sizes in each direction. After the interpolator is created, it needs to be evaluated on a new grid; its call method takes a different kind of grid format, prepared with `mgrid`.

```
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

values = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(40, 50, 60)).astype(np.uint8)  # example

steps = [0.5, 0.5, 2.0]    # original step sizes
x, y, z = [steps[k] * np.arange(values.shape[k]) for k in range(3)]  # original grid
f = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), values)    # interpolator

dx, dy, dz = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0    # new step sizes
new_grid = np.mgrid[0:x[-1]:dx, 0:y[-1]:dy, 0:z[-1]:dz]   # new grid
new_grid = np.moveaxis(new_grid, (0, 1, 2, 3), (3, 0, 1, 2))  # reorder axes for evaluation
new_values = f(new_grid)
```

Downside: e.g., when a dimension is reduced by 2, it will in effect drop every other value, which is simple downsampling. Ideally, one should average neighboring values in this case.  In terms of signal  processing, low-pass filtering precedes downsampling in [decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TorchIO](http://torchio.rtfd.io/) for that:

```py
import torchio as tio
image = tio.ScalarImage(sFileName)
resample = tio.Resample(1)
resampled = resample(image)
```

Comment: Do you have any opinions about my answer? I am asking because I am looking for a cubic interpolation method for this task.

Comment: You can also use TorchIO! I believe the B-spline in ITK has order 3, so you could do `resample = tio.Resample(1, image_interpolation='bspline')`.

Answer (score 1):

The best modern solution must include the use of the ITK library for Python.

### Assumptions

I am assuming your data is binarized for each object! You should probably use deep neural networks if you are working with colors or even greyscale, but this is outside of the scope

### Methodology

I would use the [morphological interpolation extension](https://github.com/KitwareMedical/ITKMorphologicalContourInterpolation) for ITK. You need to add the spacing between each image plane manually. So say your XYZ ratio is 1:1:7, add 7 empty planes between each image plane, and use the new matrix as the main argument for your function.

Make sure to adhere to a `dtype` supported by the library. I used `np.uint8` for my array `dtype`.

### Implementation

```py
from typing import Union

import itk
import numpy as np
from yaspin import yaspin
from yaspin.spinners import Spinners

INTERPOLATION_TEXT = "Interpolating for the first time"


@yaspin(Spinners.bouncingBall, text=INTERPOLATION_TEXT)
def morphological_interpolation(
    labeled_stack: np.ndarray, stack_depth_spacing: Union[float, int]
):
    spacing_array = np.zeros(
        (round(stack_depth_spacing), *labeled_stack.shape[1:]),
        dtype=labeled_stack.dtype,
    )

    spaced_stack = []
    for xy_plane in labeled_stack:
        spaced_stack.append(np.expand_dims(xy_plane, axis=0))
        spaced_stack.append(spacing_array)
    spaced_stack.pop(-1)
    spaced_stack = np.concatenate(spaced_stack)
    spaced_stack.astype(labeled_stack.dtype, copy=False)

    return itk.GetArrayFromImage(
        itk.morphological_contour_interpolator(itk.GetImageFromArray(spaced_stack))
    )
```

Comment: @dgrat, your xyz ratio is 0.5x0.5x2 mm -> 1:1:4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  perfrom resample operation directly on MR image, you can use antspy, it will resample the data, and change the voxel spacing info.

```
    spacing = (1,1,1)
    import ants
    img = ants.image_read(file)
    filin = ants.resample_image(img,spacing,False,1)
    ants.image_write(filin,output)
```

Answer (score -1):

I use `grid_sample` in `torch.nn.functional`.  It is convenient when you want to resample 3d arrays on non-uniformly distributed points.

Below is an example code.  You can specify resampling points by changing `grid` in the code.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

def resize_by_grid_sample(x):

    dx = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 8)
    dy = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 32)
    dz = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 32)
    meshx, meshy, meshz = torch.meshgrid((dx, dy, dz))
    grid = torch.stack((meshx, meshy, meshz), 3)
    grid = grid.unsqueeze(0)

    x = x[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, :, :]
    x = torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=False)

    out = F.grid_sample(x, grid, align_corners=True)
    out = out.data.numpy()
    out = np.squeeze(out)

    return out


data = np.random.normal(size=(32,32,32)).astype(np.float32)

# grid_sample
resized_data = resize_by_grid_sample(data)
```

I referred code [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-resize-3d-numpy-array/70338/4).

The difference between  `align_corners=True` and `align_corners=False` is literally whether or not we align corner pixels before and after resizing. [nice figure here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-we-should-use-align-corners-false/22663/9)

Comment: I too stumbled upon these functions when looking for a method; however, the OP wants to interpolate. Neither zoom nor grid_sample has this functionality. You could argue that zoom does have interpolation; moreover, the methods that are available are mostly useless when it comes to voxel interpolation.