# What is the best script in python that replicates matlabs imresize3?

Tags: python, matlab

I am translating code from MATLAB to python but cannot perfectly replicate the results of MATLAB's imresize3. My input is a 101x101x101 array. First four inputs ([0,0:3,0] or (1,1:4,1)) are: 0.3819   0.4033  0.4336  0.2767. The data input for both languages is identical.

```
sampleQDNormSmall = imresize3(sampleQDNorm,0.5);
```

This results in a 51x51x51 array where the first four values (1,1:4,1) for example are: 0.3443    0.2646    0.2700    0.2835

Now I've tried two different pieces of code in python to replicate these results:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.transform import rescale

sampleQDNormSmall = resize(sampleQDNorm,(0.5*sampleQDNorm.shape[0],0.5*sampleQDNorm.shape[1],0.5*sampleQDNorm.shape[2]),order=3,anti_aliasing=True);

sampleQDNormSmall1=rescale(sampleQDNorm,0.5,order=3,anti_aliasing=True)
```

The first one gives a 51x51x51 array that has the first four values [0,0:3,0] of: 0.3452    0.2669  0.2774  0.3099. Which is very close but not exactly the same numerical outputs. I don't know enough about the optional arguments to know might get me a better result.

The second one gives a 50x50x50 array that has the first four values [0,0:3,0] of: 0.3422   0.2623  0.2810  0.3006. This is a different output array size and also doesn't reproduce the same numerical outputs as the MATLAB code or the other python function

I don't know enough about the optional arguments to know might get me a better result. I know for this type of array, MATLAB's default is cubic interpolation which is why I am using order 3 in python. The default for anti-aliasing in both is true. I have a two bigger arrays that I am having the same issues with: a (873x873x873) array and a bool (873x873x873) array.

The MATLAB code I'm using is considered the "correct answer" for the work I am doing so I am trying to replicate the results as accurately as possible into python. Please let me know what I can try in python to reproduce the correct data.

sampleQDNorm is roughly random decimals between 0 and 1 for `[0:100,0:100,0:100]` and is padded with zeros on sides `[:,:,101],[:,101,:],[101,:,:]`

Answer (score 2):

Getting the exact same result as MATLAB `imresize3` is challenging.

One reason is that MATLAB enables [Antialiasing filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233365/how-antialiasing-implemented-in-imresize-of-matlab) by default, and I can't seem to find the equivalent Python implementation.

The closet existing Python alternatives are described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775621/interpolate-resize-3d-array).
[scipy.ndimage.zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) supports 3D resizing.
It could be that `skimage.transform.resize` gives closer result, but none are identical to MATLAB result.

---

Reimplementing `imresize3`:

Looking at the MATLAB implementation of `imresize3` (MATLAB source code), it is apparent that MATLAB implementation "simply" uses resize along each axis:

- Resize (by half) along the vertical axis.
- Resize the above result (by half) along the horizontal axis.
- Resize the above result (by half) along the depth axis.

Here is a MATLAB codes sample that demonstrates the implementation (using cubic interpolation):

```matlab
I1 = imread('peppers.png');
I2 = imresize(imread('autumn.tif'), [size(I1, 1), size(I1, 2)]);
I3 = imresize(imread('football.jpg'), [size(I1, 1), size(I1, 2)]);
I4 = imresize(imread('cameraman.tif'), [size(I1, 1), size(I1, 2)]);
I = cat(3, I1, I2, I3, I4);
J = imresize3(I, 0.5, 'cubic', 'Antialiasing', false);

imwrite(I1, '/Tmp/I1.png');
imwrite(I2, '/Tmp/I2.png');
imwrite(I3, '/Tmp/I3.png');
imwrite(I4, '/Tmp/I4.png');

imwrite(J(:,:,1), '/Tmp/J1.png');
imwrite(J(:,:,2), '/Tmp/J2.png');
imwrite(J(:,:,3), '/Tmp/J3.png');
imwrite(J(:,:,4), '/Tmp/J4.png');
imwrite(J(:,:,5), '/Tmp/J5.png');

K = cubicResize3(I, 0.5);

max_abs_diff = max(abs(double(J(:)) - double(K(:))));

disp(['max_abs_diff = ', num2str(max_abs_diff)])


function B = cubicResize3(A, scale)
    order = [1 2 3];
    
    B = A;
    for k = 1:numel(order)
        dim = order(k);       
        B = cubicResizeAlongDim(B, dim, scale);
    end    
end


function out = cubicResizeAlongDim(in, dim, scale)
    % If dim is 3, permute the input matrix so that the third dimension
    % becomes the first dimension.  This way, we can resize along the
    % third dimensions as though we were resizing along the first dimension.
    isThirdDimResize = (dim == 3);
    if isThirdDimResize
        in = permute(in, [3 2 1]);
        dim = 1;
    end
    
    if dim == 1
        out_rows = round(size(in, 1)*scale);
        out_cols = size(in, 2);
    else % dim == 2
        out_rows = size(in, 1);
        out_cols = round(size(in,2)*scale);
    end
    
    out = zeros(out_rows, out_cols, size(in, 3), class(in));  % Allocate array for storing the output.
    
    for i = 1:size(in, 3)
        % Resize each color plane separately
        out(:, :, i) = imresize(in(:, :, i), [out_rows, out_cols], 'bicubic', 'Antialiasing', false);
    end

    % Permute back so that the original dimensions are restored if we were
    % resizing along the third dimension.
    if isThirdDimResize
        out = permute(out, [3 2 1]);
    end
end
```

The result is `max_abs_diff = 0`, meaning that `cubicResize3` and `imresize3` gave the same output.

Note:
The above implementation stores images in `Tmp` folder to be used a input for testing Python implementation.

---

Here is a Python implementation using OpenCV:

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2
#from scipy.ndimage import zoom

def cubic_resize_along_dim(inp, dim, scale):
    """ Implementation is based on MATLAB source code of resizeAlongDim function """
    # If dim is 3, permute the input matrix so that the third dimension
    # becomes the first dimension.  This way, we can resize along the
    # third dimensions as though we were resizing along the first dimension.
    is_third_dim_resize = (dim == 2)
    if is_third_dim_resize:
        inp = np.swapaxes(inp, 2, 0).copy()  # in = permute(in, [3 2 1])
        dim = 0
    
    if dim == 0:
        out_rows = int(np.round(inp.shape[0]*scale))  # out_rows = round(size(in, 1)*scale);
        out_cols = inp.shape[1]  # out_cols = size(in, 2);
    else: # dim == 1
        out_rows = inp.shape[0]  # out_rows = size(in, 1);
        out_cols = int(np.round(inp.shape[1]*scale))  # out_cols = round(size(in,2)*scale);
    
    out = np.zeros((out_rows, out_cols, inp.shape[2]), inp.dtype)  # out = zeros(out_rows, out_cols, size(in, 3), class(in));  % Allocate array for storing the output.
    
    for i in range(inp.shape[2]):
        # Resize each color plane separately
        out[:, :, i] = cv2.resize(inp[:, :, i], (out_cols, out_rows), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)  # out(:, :, i) = imresize(inp(:, :, i), [out_rows, out_cols], 'bicubic', 'Antialiasing', false);

    # Permute back so that the original dimensions are restored if we were
    # resizing along the third dimension.
    if is_third_dim_resize:
        out = np.swapaxes(out, 2, 0) # out = permute(out, [3 2 1]);

    return out


def cubic_resize3(a, scale):
    b = a.copy()
    for k in range(3):
        b = cubic_resize_along_dim(b, k, scale)

    return b


# Build 3D input image (10 channels with resolution 512x384).
i1 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('/Tmp/I1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
i2 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('/Tmp/I2.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
i3 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('/Tmp/I3.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
i4 = cv2.imread('/Tmp/I4.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
im = np.dstack((i1, i2, i3, i4))  # Stack arrays along the third axis

# Read and adjust MATLAB output (out_mat is used as reference for testing).
# out_mat is the result of J = imresize3(I, 0.5, 'cubic', 'Antialiasing', false);
j1 = cv2.imread('/Tmp/J1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
j2 = cv2.imread('/Tmp/J2.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
j3 = cv2.imread('/Tmp/J3.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
j4 = cv2.imread('/Tmp/J4.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
j5 = cv2.imread('/Tmp/J5.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
out_mat = np.dstack((j1, j2, j3, j4, j5))  # Stack arrays along the third axis

#out_py = zoom(im, 0.5, order=3, mode='reflect')

# Execute 3D resize in Python
out_py = cubic_resize3(im, 0.5)

abs_diff = np.absolute(out_mat.astype(np.int16) - out_py.astype(np.int16))

print(f'max_abs_diff = {abs_diff.max()}')
```

The Python implementation reads the input files stored by MATLAB (and convert from BGR to RGB when required).

The implementation compares the result of `cubic_resize3` with the MATLAB output of `imresize3`.

The maximum difference is `12` (not zero).
Apparently `cv2.resize` and MATLAB `imresize` gives slightly different results.

---

### Update:

Replacing:
`out[:, :, i] = cv2.resize(inp[:, :, i], (out_cols, out_rows), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)`
with:
`out[:, :, i] = transform.resize(inp[:, :, i], (out_rows, out_cols), order=3, mode='edge', anti_aliasing=False, preserve_range=True)`
Reduces the maximum difference to `4`.